# Is it possible to dynamic assigning permission to a new community user on creation

Tags: community

We have a scenario is that a community user could dynamically create new community users and also assign the permission on the creation process.

E.g.: the new user A can read a document and the new user B can NOT read a document.

As far as I know, each community only allows one community profile associated with the community. Meaning even I could assign users with different profiles. Only specific community user could log in into the community site at a time

Any thought or direction to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a capability for community users to create additional community users?

Comment: One community can have multiple profiles..And people from diff profile can login into community...This is OOB feature...Are you not able to setup it?

Answer (score 0):

The user who can create a new user is like a delegated admin. if you need to increase the privilege level of the new user you can permission set. These permission sets can be assigned from apex code.